# Define function n variables

Tags: function-construction

I have function :   $ \partial_{Ax}(x_{i},\dots,x_{n}) = \Sigma_{i,j} A_{i,j}x_{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}. $

where $\partial Ax$ denotes differentiation the vector $Ax$, where $A$ is endomorphism of ${R^n}$.

For example:   $ \partial_{Ax}(x_{1},x_{2}) = A_{1,1}x_{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}} + A_{1,2}x_{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}} +  A_{2,1}x_{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}} + A_{2,2}x_{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}} $

I try define like that where `n=2` and `matrixA` is random matrix $2x2$

```
 dAx[Subscript[x, 1] _, Subscript[x, 2] _] := 
    Sum[ matrixA[[i]][[j]] *  Subscript[x, i] * 
    D[Subscript[x, j], {Subscript[x, j], 1}], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];
```

Substric[x,i] mean $x_i$

Output of `dAx[3,0]` is same as input. What is incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both your description and your code are quite confusing (at least to me). For example, I don't understand what "$End(R^n)$" signifies, so I chose to just ignore that and treat **A** as an arbitrary matrix. I also wasn't certain whether you want a vector or a scalar operator. Anyway, I think what you're asking for can be expressed as something close to the following:

```
f[A_?MatrixQ, x_?VectorQ] /; Equal @@ Dimensions[A] && Length[x] == Length[A] :=
 Block[{Function, D},
  Sum[
    A[[ii, jj]] x[[ii]] D[#, x[[jj]]],
    {jj, Last@Dimensions[A]},
    {ii, First@Dimensions[A]}
   ] &
 ]
```

For example, it gives:

```
ff = f[Array[A, {2, 2}], Array[x, 2]]
(* -> A[1, 1]*D[#1, x[1]]*x[1] + A[1, 2]*D[#1, x[2]]*x[1] +
      A[2, 1]*D[#1, x[1]]*x[2] + A[2, 2]*D[#1, x[2]]*x[2] & *)
```

which is a function that operates on some expression that is a function of the elements of the vector **x**, such as

```
ff[x[1] Log[x[2]]]
(* -> A[2, 2]*x[1] +          A[1, 1]*Log[x[2]]*x[1] +
      (A[1, 2]*x[1]^2)/x[2] + A[2, 1]*Log[x[2]]*x[2]   *)
```

Maybe it's what you wanted; maybe not. If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: What is the purpose of specifying `{Function, D}` as `Block` first argument (instead of `Block[{}`)?

Comment: @anderstood because we do not want `Function` or `D` to have their usual meanings while we construct this operator. Try it without and see what the result will be. `Block` with an empty localization list would be useless.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks. It's what I wanted. :)